# How to statically save a dynamic value to another cell at a certain instant?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In my sheet I have a cell (let's say "A1") whose value changes dynamically by formulas on the same sheet. 
I want to save the value that cell A1 contains at a given instant (say, 00:00 on 01/01/2023) in another cell (say, "B1"). 
Is it possibile? I have no experience with macros or Apps Script, but such a solution is nevertheless welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to copy the value of cell "A1" to "B1" without including the formula.
- You want to run the script at a specific date.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. And, please run `installTrigger`. By this, a time-driven trigger is installed. By this, the script of `main` is run at `00:00 on 01/01/2023` in your timezone.

```js
function installTrigger() {
  const functionName = "main";
  const trigger = ScriptApp.getScriptTriggers().find(e => e.getHandlerFunction() == functionName);
  if (trigger) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(trigger);
  }
  ScriptApp.newTrigger(functionName).timeBased().at(new Date(2023, 0, 1)).create();
}

function main() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const srcRange = sheet.getRange("A1");
  const dstRange = sheet.getRange("B1");
  srcRange.copyTo(dstRange, { contentsOnly: true });
}
```

- Also, even when you directly run `main`, the script works. When `main` is run, in Sheet1, the cell "A1" is copied to "B1" without including the formula.

#### References:

- [copyTo(destination, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options)
- [Class TriggerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder)

Comment: Thanks! This seems perfect, I only changed the 0 in the `Date(2023, 0, 1)` function to 1. So I ran only `installTrigger`: can you confirm that on 01/01/2023 my sheet will update automatically?

Comment: @FranzGoogle Thank you for replying. About `So I ran only installTrigger: can you confirm that on 01/01/2023 my sheet will update automatically?`, in this case, I think that you can check at the script editor. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) Please check it after you ran the function `installTrigger`.

Comment: Thank you. I checked and found an activator with the following specifications: 1) deployment: head; 2) event: time-driven; 3) function: main. Is it ok?

Comment: @FranzGoogle Thank you for replying. Yes. In that situation, the installable trigger has already been installed. And, when you click the pencil button, you can see the date and time. By the way, `0` of `new Date(2023, 0, 1)` means January. In this case, the start number is `0`. Please be careful about this.

Comment: Thank you, this is great. Also the months number system is clear!

Comment: @FranzGoogle Thank you for replying. About `Thank you, this is great. Also the months number system is clear!` and this current situation, if your issue was still not resolved, could you please tell me? I would like to think of the current issue and modify my answer.

Comment: At the moment my issue is resolved, but I’ll know if it’s correctly resolved in few months.

Answer (score 1):

Run the trigger create function and it will call the save cell function every day near midnight.  The saveCell function will save the value of A1 in A2

```
function saveCell() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet Name");
  sh.getRange("A2").setValue(sh.getRange("A1").getValue());
}


function createTimeBasedTriggerForSaveCell() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("saveCell").timeBased().everyDays(1).atHour(0).create();
}
```